# Docker "not found" for existing file

Tags: linux, docker, filesystems, docker-machine

I am using Docker to build an electron node app and I'm getting some odd behavior. The build seems successful but when I run the electron app I get a "not found" error but the file does exist. I can ls the file and cat the file but cannot source/execute the file.

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src
WORKDIR /usr/src
COPY package.json /usr/src
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src
RUN npm run build:linux 
ENTRYPOINT "/usr/src/docker-entrypoint.sh"
```

This will result in the generation of this directory:

```
/usr/src/app/builds/app-linux-x64
```

With a bunch of files including an executable named **app**.

```
/usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 5: ./app: not found
```

It does exist.

```
/usr/src/app/builds/app-linux-x64 # ls -lah
total 124472
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root        4.0K Apr 28 20:07 .
drwxrwxr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Apr 28 20:07 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        1.0K Apr 28 20:07 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        1.6M Apr 28 20:07 LICENSES.chromium.html
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       24.3K Apr 28 20:07 blink_image_resources_200_percent.pak
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          15 Apr 28 20:07 content_resources_200_percent.pak
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        9.7M Apr 28 20:07 content_shell.pak
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        9.7M Apr 28 20:07 icudtl.dat
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        2.8M Apr 28 20:07 libffmpeg.so
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       19.4M Apr 28 20:07 libnode.so
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Apr 28 20:07 locales
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      334.7K Apr 28 20:07 natives_blob.bin
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      136.6K Apr 28 20:07 pdf_viewer_resources.pak
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Apr 28 20:07 resources
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      970.2K Apr 28 20:07 snapshot_blob.bin
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       76.7M Apr 28 20:07 app
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      159.4K Apr 28 20:07 ui_resources_200_percent.pak
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           6 Apr 28 20:07 version
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       58.7K Apr 28 20:07 views_resources_200_percent.pak
```

I can ls it:

```
/usr/src/app/builds/app-linux-x64 # ls -lah app
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       76.7M Apr 28 20:07 app
```

But I cannot run it:

```
/usr/src/app/builds/app-linux-x64 # ./app 
/bin/sh: ./app: not found
```

Comment: something strange `WORKDIR /usr/src
COPY . /usr/src` so you copy from .usr.src to /usr/src

Comment: What's is app, is it a binary or shell script? If the latter, what's the first line of the file?

Comment: @user2915097 The copy command takes files from the build context in . and copies them into the container, and workdir changes directories inside the container. The build context is a completely different location.

Comment: Can you run `file app` inside of the container? The executable might not be compatible with the architecture of the machine you're trying to run it on

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem myself which was solved by putting sh infront of the script to run. For you it would be:

```
ENTRYPOINT "sh" "/usr/src/docker-entrypoint.sh"
```